# Proving a simple lemma...

Tags: real-analysis

If a,b > o and a>b then 1/a < 1/b. What is the simple proof for this lemma? I think it involves something alone the lines of multiplying both sides of a>b by 1/a and 1/b...

Thank you for any responses.

Comment: Multiply both sides by $\dfrac 1{ab}\color{grey}{>0}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac1a-\frac1b=\frac{b-a}{ab}<0$$ as $a,b>0$ and $a>b\iff b<a$

Comment: I found a solution:

Since a,b > 0, we can multiply both sides of a>b and we can do this without changing the direction of the inequality:

Multiply each side by 1/a: a/a > b/a => 1 > b/a Then multiply each side by 1/b: 1/b > b/ab => 1/b > 1/a. QED.

Does this make sense?

Comment: @LeonLeibovici,have you noticed GitGud's comment in the Question?

Comment: Whoops! So we're saying the same thing except mine is just a bit longer. Thanks @GidGud !